# Incremental backups taking longer than usual in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

There are total 3 D nodes each have 2 forests so there are total 6 forests in the cluster.

Out of 6, incremental backup for 5 forests is getting completed in 15-25 mins, one forest is taking longer than 1.30 hours.

I don't see any issue related to Space, and the forests are rebalanced properly.

Incremental backup for all forests occurs every 2 hours.

Comment: Is that one forest consistently slower than the rest on every incremental backup? Is that slow forest merging? Do you have a background-io-limit set? Incrementals every two hours is a rather short window, what is the frequency of your full backups?

Comment: Yes, only one forest is taking longer.
There is no merging.
io-limit - how to check that?
full backups occur once a day.

Comment: background-io-limit is a group level setting, but unless you have explicitly set it, not likely to be holding you back. If the one forest backing up slowly is on the same storage as another that is backing up quicker, then it is more likely that there is just a lot of changes in that forest since the last backup. Do you see any significant deltas for that host in meters (read rates, backup write rate, etc)?

Comment: I don't think so there is any extra change in that forest. Slowness is being observed all the times. checked the `background-io-limit` also it is set to zero